# How to get the lowest price of products?

Tags: ms-access-2010

Table structure
[image]

The above Table have 10 products with various price from 3 suppliers. I need to pick the supplier who can give the lowest price.

Just i tried with MS Access 2013. I unable to get the lowest price. Your valuable guidance is much appreciate one.

```
SID = Supplier ID
PCODE = Product Code
```

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

I assume cheapest means lowest per-ml price per item
So do the following:

1. create a query#1 that includes the product, supplier, whatever other
   fields you want in the final answer, and a calculated field of the
   per-ml price.
2. create an aggregate query #2 on query#1, which groups by product and gives the min per_ml_price. Now you have a "table" with the cheapest price for each product.
3. Lastly, you want to find the data that matches the lowest price. (Inner-)Join query#2 and query#1, and output the fields you want (product, supplier, etc.)

Comment: Already i got the min value of product. But i unable to match the value with supplier query and get the supplier who can give the lowest price. I mean the step of # 3. Can u able to explain the Step #3

Comment: Well, you are looking for the min price for product, so look up the product from query 2 in query 1 which has the detail.
Technically that means join the queries on the product field. You may get dups depending on the data, but that seems valid.